# Error in group by, tell me that "applied to an object of class "function""

Tags: r, group-by

I am trying to sum the dates of a table by days. I have more than a million dates to add.
I created the table with this formula

```
serie <- data.frame(comments$created_time, sentiment2$positive, sentiment2$negative)
```

Then I applied this to add dates and sentiment values

```
df %>% 
  group_by(as.Date(comments.created_time)) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(sentiment))
```

but it gives me this error

> Error in UseMethod("group_by") :
> no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function" `

What should I do?

Comment: You should first try changing `df` to `serie`, and then updating the code to make sure it matches your column names.

Comment: Perhaps `comments.created_time` was intended to be `comments$created_time`?

Comment: Better yet, don't reference the original data.frame at all and use tidyselect. I.e. change `comments.created_time` to `created_time`.

Comment: ok i solved, where to change `df`, thanks a lot